# Remove 2 trailing zero's in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a dataframe like the below and want to remove trailing zeros in pairs of 2.

```
col1
99990000
11100000
22220000
```

```
data = {'col1': ['99990000', '11100000', '22220000']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
```

desired result

```
col1
9999
1110
2222
```

The below removes all trailing zeros not and not keeping 1110?

```
df['col1'].str.replace('00+$','')
df['col1'].str.rstrip('00')
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `00+` applies the repeater `+` only to the last `0`, you need to use a group:

```
df['col1'].str.replace('(00)+$','')
```

Output:

```
0    9999
1    1110
2    2222
Name: col1, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to conceptualize the regex, here is an example. The solution from @mozway is much better but this focuses on the substitution only, ignoring pandas:

```
import re
col1 = [re.sub(r'(00)+$', '', num) for num in
              ['99990000', '11100000', '22220000']]
# ['9999', '1110', '2222']
```

- [`(00)+$`](https://regex101.com/r/1IVn5T/2)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it should work

```
df['col1'].str[:4]
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).